# Excel remove only unique cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have been struggling with coming up with a solution to deleting all cells that are unique across my excel sheet.

I have an excel sheet that look something like this:

```
cat    dog    shrimp    donkey
dog    human  wale      
wale   bear

dog    donkey shrimp    human    wale
```

and I would like to now remove all values that are unique amongst all cells (so here that would be removing cat and bear) while keeping all the order of all the rows etc. intact.
I also have a few rows that are completely empty (but that I can't delete).

I have tried the following macro, but it's my first vba macro (and I know it is stupidly inefficient :) ) For some reason it doesn't delete anything whereas I can't see the logic error.

Code:

```
Sub doit()
Dim rng As Range
Dim rngtoCheck As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim isCellUnique As Boolean
Dim cellToCheck As Range

Set rng = Range("A1:Z20")
Set rngtoCheck = Range("A1:Z20")

For Each cell In rng
    isCellUnique = True

    For Each cellToCheck In rngtoCheck

        If cell.Value = cellToCheck.Value AND cell.row <> cellToCheck.row Then
            isCellUnique = False
        End If

    Next cellToCheck

    If isCellUnique = True Then
        cell.ClearContents
    End If

Next cell


End Sub
```

The idea is that I loop through the entire range and for each cell I check if any other cell in the range has the same value, but is not on the same row. If both check out I keep the value, otherwise I clear the cell.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error are you getting?  I just ran this with the same data and it ran just fine (cat/bear removed).

Comment: I just tried it as well again and now it works for me too. I have no idea why it wouldn't do anything on the excel sheet the first times. Very strange. Sorry for the trouble...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf` to check if the cell is repeated more than once?

Is this what you are trying?

**Tried And Tested**

```
Sub doit()
    Dim rng As Range, aCell As Range

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z20")

    For Each aCell In rng
        If Not Len(Trim(aCell.Value)) = 0 Then
            '~~> Check if word occurs just once
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, aCell.Value) = 1 Then
                MsgBox aCell.Value & " is unique"
                '
                '~~> Do what you want here
                '
            End If
        End If
    Next aCell
End Sub
```